# What is Java type returned by getObject(int columnIndex, Map<String, Class<?>> map) for NUMBER

Tags: java, jdbc

Why in the following o is a `java.math.BigDecimal` and not a `String`? How this method is expected to work?

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     Connection conn =
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/pdb1.us.oracle.com",
"restdev", "restdev");
     Map<String, Class<?>> typeMap = new java.util.HashMap<>();
     typeMap.put("NUMBER", String.class);

     Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select 123 from dual");
     rs.next();
     Object o = rs.getObject(1, typeMap);

     System.out.println(o.getClass());
   }
}
```

Comment: Some drivers don't support the typemap, others only support it for the non-standard types (aka user defined types), not for the standard types.

Answer (score 0):

Behavior depends on the driver you are using, but in general you have only a limited set of Java types that you can materialize result to. In case you specify anything else you might end up either with fallback default type or Exception.

You can see an example of this mapping e.g. here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/apxref.htm
and more specifically for Oracle JDBC driver http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/datacc.htm#JJDBC28403

Comment: Even I change to map to `typeMap.put("NUMBER", java.lang.Integer.class);` the output is still `java.math.BigDecimal`

Comment: I think this would be more appropriate link for your JDBC driver. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/datacc.htm#g1061775 The only valid type for `NUMBER` is `BigDecimal`

Answer (score 0):

Yor map was ignored by the driver because you should have provided classes' names which implement [SQLData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLData.html). Altough it is not explicitly set in [getObject(int,Map)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject(int,%20java.util.Map))'s documentation, you can see it mentioned in [getObject(int,Class)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject(int,%20java.lang.Class)).

Read all about SQLData to learn how to set yor own custom mapping.